# A question concerning the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given a pair of relatively prime integers $m$ and $n$, with $|m| + |n| > 1$, can I always find integers $a$ and $b$ such that am + bn = $\pm$ 1 and $|m| + |n| > |a| + |b|$.

Comment: How can two nonzero integers ever *not* be |m|+|n| > 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to show every integer can be expressed uniquely in the form $ma+nb$ with $a\in\{0,1,2\dots |n|-1\}$. This is the expression we want. We just have to show that $|b|\leq m$.

suppose not, then $|nb|\geq|(m+1)||n|$ and $|am|\leq (|n|-1)|m|$ which clearly implies by the triangle inequality that:

$|am+nb|> |(m+1)||n|-(|n|-1)|m| > 1$,a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $|m|=1$ let $a=1$ and $b=0.$

If $|n|=1$ let $a=0$ and $b=1.$

If $|m|\ne 1\ne |n|,$ take integer $A$ satisfying $1\leq A\leq |n|-1$ and $Am\equiv 1 \pmod n.$ Let $a=\min (A,|n|-A).$ We have $$am\equiv\pm 1\pmod n$$ and $$|n/2|\geq |a|.$$ So $am+bn=\pm 1$ where $b$ is an integer . Now $$|nm/2|\geq  |a|\cdot |m|=|am|=|-bn\pm 1|\geq |bn|-1  \implies$$ $$\implies  |nm/2|\geq |bn|-1\implies $$ $$\implies  |m/2|+1\geq |m/2|+|1/n|\geq |b|.$$ Hence $$|a|+|b|\leq |n/2|+|m/2|+1<|n|+|m|$$ because if $m,n$ are co-prime and $|m|\ne 1\ne |n|$ then $|n|+|m|\geq 5.$